# Yup validation for checkbox group with separate custom write-in option

Tags: reactjs, yup

I have a React form in which the options are supplied and we add on a separate custom write-in option:

```
const CheckboxWithCustomOption = (props) => {
    const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
    const [isOtherSelected, setIsOtherSelected] = useState<boolean>(false)

    const onChange = () => {
        // If we select one of the regular options, we want to blur out the text field.
        inputRef.current?.blur()
    }

    const onOtherSelect = (e) => {
        setIsOtherSelected(!isOtherSelected)

        // If the "Other" button is checked, then put focus on the associated text box.
        // If the "Other" button is unchecked, then blur the text box and clear out any values in it.
        if (e.target.checked) {
            inputRef.current?.focus()
        } else {
            inputRef.current?.blur()
            inputRef.current?.value = ''
        }
        
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {props.options.map(option => (
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id={option.id}
                    name="regularOptions"
                    value={option.value}
                    onChange={onChange}
                />
            )}
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="otherOption"
                value="Other"
                onClick={onOtherSelect}
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                disabled={!isOtherSelected}
                ref={inputRef}
                name="otherText"
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Now, I am trying to write a Yup validation schema for this component. The user must pick at least one option. If they select the "Other" option, they must enter an input between 5 and 20 characters.

```
{
    otherOption: yup.array().notRequired(),
    otherText: yup.string().when("otherOption", value => {
        return value[0] === 'Other' ? yup.string().required().min(5).max(20) : yup.string().notRequired()
    }),
    regularOptions: yup.array().when("otherOption", value => {
        return value[0] === 'Other' ? yup.array().notRequired() : yup.array().min(1)
    }),
}
```

However, this validation does not appear to behave properly for my form. I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `when` statement, you need to use `if-then-otherwise` statements to get conditional validation working.

I have fixed your code:

```
{
    otherOption: yup.array().notRequired(),
    regularOptions: yup.array().when("otherOption", {
        is: (val) => val[0] === 'Other',
        then: yup.array().notRequired(),
        otherwise: yup.array().min(1)
    }),
    otherText: yup.string().when("otherOption", {
        is: (val) => val[0] === 'Other',
        then: yup.string().required().min(5).max(20)
        otherwise: yup.string().notRequired(),
    }),
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I get a red squiggly line on the `is` property:

`Argument of type '{ is: (val: any) => boolean; then: ArraySchema<Maybe<any[] | undefined>, AnyObject, undefined, "">; otherwise: ArraySchema<any[] | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConditionBuilder<ArraySchema<any[] | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'is' does not exist in type 'ConditionBuilder<ArraySchema<any[] | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">>'.ts(2769)`

Comment: @noblerare What is your `yup` version? Looks like this issue: https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1912

Comment: That's just what I needed. Thank you!